# Sublime Text 2: Regex to remove block containing certain characters

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

My raw text file is like

```
>
 item1
>
item{2}
>
item3
>
item4}
```

I would like to remove/match all items containing { or }. In the example above, it would be removing item 2 and 4. The result would be:

```
>
 item1
>
item3
```

I want to do greedy match so it matches the minimum block. It also has to match over multiple lines. like:

```
(?s)>(.+?)[\{|\}](.+?)>
```

But it's not working properly for me.

Answer (score 1):

This regex does exactly what you asked for. It assumes that exact type of input, with nothing else on the line above the one which contains `{` or `}`.

```
>\n.*?[{}]+.*?$
```

If that line could have text on it, the following one works.

```
>.*\n.*?[{}]+.*?$
```

Both these replaces will leave a blank line. To avoid this, add `\n` either in front or the back of the regex, depending on what fits your document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\n>\s(.*)(\{|\})
```